# fill ouline of arc in html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, graphics, html5-canvas

I want to draw a shape like this using html5 canvas

[image]

but I don't want to use curves.
is there any way to draw it using arc function ?

or at least how can I draw a curve exactly like when I have given center point and radius for an arc function.

Thanks a million .

Comment: @StealingMana 's answer is just fine, but one could also see the figure you show as a rectangle drawn with an arc/circle clipped-out. Depending on which figureS you want to show, using clipping *might* be easier. I can post the code if you're interested.

Comment: I just slapped it together as one shape. Your right though @GameAlchemist, if you use the clipping method you could also center/ align the shape with more ease.

Answer (score 2):

This should help, try this:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
<script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var x = canvas.width / 2;
  var y = canvas.height / 2;
  var radius = 75;
  var startAngle = 0 * Math.PI;
  var endAngle = 1 * Math.PI;
  var counterClockwise = false;

  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, counterClockwise);
  context.lineTo(x - radius, 200);
  context.lineTo(x + radius, 200);
  context.closePath();
  context.stroke();
  context.fillStyle = 'red';
  context.fill();
</script>
```